# Changing time zone for a single user in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, time-zone

I was in Athens, now I'm temporarily in Berlin. I don't want to change the system time, it's perfectly correct. I just want the system to display the time in a different zone. I shouldn't need superuser rights to do this, I don't want to modify the default zone for the system, just for myself.

If this isn't possible through GNOME3's user interface, can I perhaps do it by editing a configuration file or something? A user configuration file that is, not system. `.bashrc` wouldn't do it I believe, it would only affect bash.

Comment: System time is actually always stored in UTC, it's just adjusted for zone/daylight at request time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible through setting the `TZ` variable.

Add this to your `~/.profile`

```
TZ='Europe/Berlin'; export TZ
```

The possible time zones are defined in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

Log out and back in to see it take effect.

See also: [Unix & Linux: Incorrect Timezone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60458/awesome-incorrect-timezone)

Comment: Thanks. I confess I could have figured this myself, but I wanted to rant a little :-)

Comment: Well, I learned something new today.